# How can I automatically open Bootstrap Tab and Collapse item from URL?

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'd like to be able to automatically open, and scroll to a specific Bootstrap tab, and then a collapse item within that tab.

I've found the code below that apparently will work with collapse items, but I want to know how I can integrate this with the tab item too.

```
var url = document.location.toString();
if ( url.match('#') ) {
    var hash = url.split('#')[1];

    // collapse the expanded panel
    $('#accordion .accordion-collapse').removeClass('in');

    // expand the requested panel
    $('#' + hash + '_c').addClass('in');
}
```

The tab I want to open is `#faq`, but in terms of the collapsible items, I'm not sure the code above is correct, as the ID for each item seems to be `#ui-id-1`, which is not only dynamically set, but also contains nothing about the contents of the tab (it's an FAQ system).

Page can be viewed at http://dev.bellavou.co.uk/face/facelift/

Any ideas on how I can visit the page, navigate to the FAQ tab, and then open a specified question/answer using a single URL (something like http://dev.bellavou.co.uk/face/facelift/#faq-what-is-the-recovery-like)

Comment: according to https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/javascript/#tabs an opened tab also has the class `active` so also remove and add it

Answer (score 0):

you can open a given tab by:

```
$('a[href="#tabid"]').tab('show');
```

then follow up with opening the collabsible as you do in your code. 
You can also set class "active" on tabs to achieve the same result.

Comment: how can I split out the URL if i put faq at the start, and then get the rest of it using the current code example? ie. `/#faq-what-is-the-recovery-like` How can individually get 'faq' and 'what-is-the-recovery-like'

Comment: I'd go for url parameters and grab them from there.. ?tab=faqid&question=questionid